# Floating point comparison in VB6

Tags: vb6, floating-point, equality

What's the best way to test two Singles for equality in VB6?

I want to test two Single values for equality to 7 significant figures.

[This MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69333) recommends using something like

```
If Abs(a - b) <= Abs(a / 10 ^ 7) Then
    valuesEqual = True
End If
```

However, that can fail for certain values, e.g.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim a As Single
    Dim b As Single

    a = 0.50000005
    b = 0.50000014

    Debug.Print "a = " & a
    Debug.Print "b = " & b
    Debug.Print "a = b: " & (a = b)
    Debug.Print "SinglesAreEqual(a, b): " & SinglesAreEqual(a, b)

    // Output:
    // a = 0.5000001
    // b = 0.5000001
    // b = b: False
    // SinglesAreEqual(a, b): False

End Sub

Private Function SinglesAreEqual(a As Single, b As Single) As Boolean

    If Abs(a - b) <= Abs(a / 10 ^ 7) Then
        SinglesAreEqual = True
    Else
        SinglesAreEqual = False
    End If

End Function
```

The simplest way I've found of getting the result I need is to convert the values to strings, but seems horribly ugly:

```
Private Function SinglesAreEqual(a As Single, b As Single) As Boolean

    SinglesAreEqual = (Str$(a) = Str$(b))

End Function
```

Are there any better ways?

Comment: I think the main problem here is thinking that a Single holds decimal data.  This makes a concept such as "7 significant figures" subject to conversion and approximation errors.  You might try converting them to Double values before performing the comparison calculation you cited.

Comment: Bob - a Single is a 4-byte floating-point value, Double is 8-byte floating-point, so significant figures are relevant. Decimal data is held in the Decimal data type.

Comment: No the "Decimal" subtype of a Variant is a scaled binary integer much as Currency is.  Your "7 figures" is "7 decimal figures" and since the Single holds binary data this is where the errors creep in.  Maybe look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164504(office.10).aspx for some clarity?  "7 figures" is pushing the limits of accuracy of a Single.

Answer (score 3):

I maintain a CAD/CAM application and I have to deal with floating point numbers all the time. I have a function that I call `fComp` that I pass a floating point value when I need to test for equality. `fComp` call a rounding function set to a certain level of precision. For our system I round to 6 decimal places. Yours may need higher or get away with lower it depends on the application.

The `fComp` Function exists so I have one spot to change the rounding factor used in these calculations. This proved handy a couple of years back when we started manufacturing higher precision machines.

```
Public Function pRound(ByVal Value As Double, ByVal Power As Double) As Double
    Dim TempValue As Double
    Dim tSign As Double
    TempValue = Value
    tSign = TempValue
    TempValue = Abs(TempValue)
    TempValue = TempValue * 10 ^ (Power * -1)
    TempValue = Fix(TempValue + 0.5)
    TempValue = TempValue / 10 ^ (Power * -1)
    pRound = TempValue * Sign(tSign)
End Function
```

To round to the 6th decimal place you go

```
RoundedNumber = pRound(MyValue, -6)
```

Negative  is to the right of the decimal place positive to the left.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to round to a certain number of significant figures, not decimal places - 123.456789 should be rounded to 123.4568 but 1.23456789 should be rounded to 1.234568

Answer (score 2):

Instead if rounding and testing for equality, you can take the difference of two numbers and compare that with a factor

`If Abs(a - b) < 0.000001 Then`

You can adjust the `0.000001` to whatever resolution you need

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can use the `single` data type to that many significant figures.  You would need to use `double` instead:

```
Dim a As Single
Dim s As String

s = "0.50000005"
a =  0.50000005

Debug.Print s & " " & a
```

The above outputs:

```
0.50000005
0.5000001
```

Comment: Try this in the immediate window "4.2 - 0.1 = 4.1". It will return false because of the way computers handle repeating numbers. You can try "4.2 - 0.1" in python idle or vb.net immediate window to see what is returned. See also http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html